# how we can place order with REST API Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Anyone know how we can place an order with Magento web API?

I need to place an order with Payflow pro and payflow express.

Can you please send me request parameter for Web API?

Comment: you can learn that from here  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-admin-token.html

Comment: Kunj,

I have read that rest API tutorial. It's helpful.

But, I want to Place an order with Payflow pro and express with API.

I have checked with different way but not able to succeed. Do you know which  parameter we can pass for placing an order??

Answer (score 0):

Good News!!

We have place an order with Payflow pro and Payflow Express with Magento 2.3.* with the help of GraphQL.

We have did some customization for same also, overight some of files to achive things.

If anyone want solution than contact me...